# How to create and display model data on a single view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The goal is to be able to create and display an unordered list item from a model within the same view.

This is what I have so far
**Model**: 
Notes.cs

```
namespace NoteTaking.Models
{
    public class Notes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public float Time { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("Notes")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace NoteTaking.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Notes.ToList());
        }

        // POST: Home
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,Text,Time")]Notes notes)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Notes.Add(notes);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model NoteTaking.Models.Notes

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}

<div>
    <h2>Notes</h2>
    @foreach (var d in Model.Text)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                @d
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

I understand that I will get a compiling error and I have tried to fix this by doing numerous things like using IEnumerable but this doesn't allow me to use the @Html.EditorFor.

I'm very confused.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Index method is returning a collection of notes

```
return View(db.Notes.ToList());
```

so the view should be

```
@model IEnumerable<NoteTaking.Models.Notes>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

which will display all `Notes`. By default this will create inputs for all 3 properties of notes.  You can create a custom `EditorTemplate` named `Notes.cshtml` in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` to customise your display

```
@model NoteTaking.Models.Notes
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Time)
```

and your POST method should be

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Notes> notes)
```

since your editing a collection of notes.

Note: There is not much point also displaying the collection in the unordered list as you have done since all notes are already displayed using `EditorFor`

**Edit**

Based on your revised requirements you need a view model that contains the properties you want to display and edit

```
public class NotesVM
{
  public List<Notes> NoteList { get; set; }
  public Notes NewNote { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  NotesVM model = new NotesVM();
  model.NewNote = new Notes();
  model.NoteList = db.Notes.ToList();
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model NotesVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewNote.Text)
  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
....
<ul>
  @foreach (var d in Model.NotesList)
  {
    <li>@d.Text</li>
  }
</ul>
```

and in the post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="NewNote")]Notes model)
{
  // Note you only have a control for `Test` so `ID` and `Time` will both be default values
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Notes.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Note I would also recommend creating a view model for class `Notes` itself so you can add validation attributes

Comment: Despite the wording of your question, looking at you view code I see that submit button text is "Create" so perhaps you really mean display a collection and create a new item? in which case that an entirely different requirement

Comment: I agree with you. It's quite very contradicting on the title of the question. But still, the thing that he wanted to achieve is possible. It's just that there are some inconsistencies on his question and the details of the question

Comment: So I think I'm getting closer, but I'm returning an error after your changes for the HomeController Index [post] method.  The line 'db.Notes.Add(notes);' says it has some invalid arguments.  Also, I plan to add a timer to the view in the future. Will this method I'm doing complicate adding the timers elapsed time float to the model?

Comment: @LouisMichael, Yes it is but (sorry) not with the code in your edited answer

Comment: Yes!  I meant to "Create" a new item and display it in the same view.  Sorry for the confusion - you guys are seriously a huge help.  I will edit my question above.

Comment: @Gadzuks, I am still unsure if you want the ability to add a new `Notes`? My code if for editing existing notes and it posts back a collection so `db.Notes.Add(notes)` is not correct (you trying to _Add_ a collection of existing `Notes` not add a new `Notes`

Comment: Yeah. I assumed it wrong and haven't tried the code yet.

Comment: You could do an AJAX/JSonResult for this if you want it. There are so many ways to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: @Gadzuks, You need a view model for this scenario that includes both the collection and a new `Notes`. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I want to add a new Notes and view it on the same page.  I'm sorry for the confusion and thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You just made my everything so much more clear!

Comment: Glad to help. Just as a side note. In your code your had `[Bind(Include = "Id,Text,Time")]` but the model only included those 3 properties so its pointless (every property is bound by default). If you ever use `Bind.Include` or `Bind.Exclude` for binding only a subset of properties, think again - you should almost always be using a view model to represent what you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are iterating an IEnumerable type in your

```
   @for (var d in Model.Text)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                @d
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
```

and your model only states

```
@model NoteTaking.Models.Notes
```

try to make it an Enumerable type:

```
@model IEnumerable<NoteTaking.Models.Notes>

/*
    Your codes here
*/
```

**EDIT:**

Now I got your point. You would want to display the newly added/edited entity on the same page. Now, you could do something like this:

```
@model NoteTaking.Models.Notes

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <div class="jumbotron"></div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    }

    <div>
        <h2>Notes</h2>
        @foreach (var d in Model.ToList())
        {
            <ul>
                <li>
                    @d.Text
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: When I use the @model IEnumerable<NoteTaking.Models.Notes> I end up getting a compiling error for the @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text).  Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using Partial views you can have a model be a collection of models, It's a really rough example, but I mocked up something that works using EF6 and a quick Code First Database...

It's not the fastest thing in the world, but demonstrates how to return a collection of results from EntityFramework that is bound to the View as it's Model.  And how to add a new item.  Many tweaks could be made to this.

One such tweak: Return the models with AsNoTracking called so they aren't being tracked (can't track accross postbacks anyways).

1. Views

   /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
   /Views/Shared/NewNote.cshtml
   /Views/Shared/Notes.cshtml
2. Controller

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       MyDbContext data = new MyDbContext();

       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           var notes = data.Notes;
           return View(notes);
       }

       public ActionResult AddNewNote(Models.Note model)
       {
           data.Notes.Add(model);
           data.SaveChanges();
           var notes = data.Notes;
           return Redirect("~/");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Model

   ```
   public class Note
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public string Text { get; set; }

       public long Time { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Model EF Config Class

   ```
   public class NoteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Note>
   {
       public NoteConfig()
       {
           this.HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p1 => p1.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
       //this.HasRequired(p => p.Text);
        }
   }
   ```
5. DBContext

   ```
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
   {
       #region DBSet
       public DbSet<Models.Note> Notes { get; set; }
       #endregion

       #region Constructor
       public MyDbContext()
           : base("Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Bin/NotesExample.sdf"))
       {
           this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
           this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
           this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
           this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
       }
       #endregion

       #region Methods
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           NoteConfig noteConfig = new NoteConfig();
           modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(noteConfig);
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       }
       #endregion
   }
   ```
6. Index.cshtml

   ```
   @{
       Layout = null;
   }

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>
           @{ Html.RenderPartial("Notes"); }
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   7. Notes.cshtml

      ```
      @model System.Data.Entity.DbSet<NotesExample.Models.Note>
      @{
          MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();
          int noteCount = Model.Count();
          var notes = Model.ToList();
      }
      @for (int i = 0; i < noteCount || (notes.Count == 0 && i == 0); ++i)
      {
          if (notes.Count == 0 || i == notes.Count - 1)
          {
              //Add New Note
              Html.RenderPartial("NewNote", new NotesExample.Models.Note());
          }
          else
          {
              //Render Exising Notes
              var note = notes[i];
              <div>
                  <h3>Note ID: @note.Id</h3>
                  <h3>Text: @note.Text</h3>
                  <h3>Time (ticks): @note.Time</h3>
              </div>
          }
      }
      ```
   8. NewNote.cshtml

      ```
      @model NotesExample.Models.Note
      @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewNote", "Home"))
      {
          <div>
          <label>New Note Text:</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Text)
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="AddNewNote" value="Add New Note" />
      }
      ```

Comment: I got lost in this and forgot it was for one view... I'll try again later.